# What are the bars protruding from this C-130?

Tags: feature-identification, airshow, c-130

This C-130 was photographed on approach to Ellington Field (EFD), Texas.

[image]

What are the protruding, truss-supported bars aft of and below the wing?

[image]

There's an airshow coming up in ~3 weeks at EFD, so it may have something to do with that, especially considering the fancy underwing paint job.

Comment: One word: chemtrails. Sometimes extra chemicals need to be spread, so they hook up the sprayer.

Comment: You must live really close to me.  I saw that guy doing patterns Sunday afternoon

Comment: I am fortunate to live in the neighborhood just SE of EFD, so we get the free airshow all the time.

Comment: @Tristan it's flying again today.

Comment: Saw it flying patterns again on Sunday 12/1.  Dude was LOW over my house

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is a civilian owned C-130 Hercules used for aerial spraying operations. It is owned by the [International Air Response](https://internationalairresponse.com/aircraft-c-130/) company based out of Mesa, AZ.

[image]

The aircraft is equipped with a RIDSS spray system for use in things like oil spill response (for spraying dispersants). [You can read more about the system here](https://internationalairresponse.com/aerial-dispersants/).

Comment: Thanks! One of the pictures at the 2nd link clearly shows the spray-bar. https://internationalairresponse.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/d2.png